# i want the second condition in the while loop to exceuted after the first condition is fullfilled and executed

Tags: c#

i have code that will execute when the condition is fulfilled using `while` loop
the problem is when the first condition is fulfilled the `loop` will run but when the second condition is fulfilled it can't enter the `loop`

here my code

```
public bool isDetected = true;
Thread th = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(() => 
            {
                while (isDetected == false)
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
                    {
                        if (predictedLabel.Content.ToString() != "")
                        {
                            debugText.AppendText("Thread1\n");
                            //await SendMsg();
                            await Task.Delay(2000);
                            x = 0;
                            isDetected = true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });                
        });

        Thread th2 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(() =>
            {
                while (isDetected == true)
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
                    {
                        if ((displayHandCount.Content.ToString() == "Hands: 1" || displayHandCount.Content.ToString() == "Hands: 2"))
                        
                        {
                                 
                                isDetected = false;
                                x = 1;
                                await Task.Delay(2000);
                                await prediction();
                                await Task.Delay(3000);
                                
                            
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            th.Start();
            th2.Start();
```

the problem is after the first condition in `th2`is fulfilled and the code in it is executed, automatically the second condition in `th1` is fulfilled but the second condition is not executed

i want the code to work like when after the first condition is fullfilled the second condition will run.

Comment: you have to use && not ||

Comment: You are mixing about 3 completely different concurrency models that do not really play well with each other. Pick one and write your code again from scratch.

Comment: BTW: I think you do not need concurrency here _at all_.